# Kendo databinding in templates

Tags: javascript, templates, data-binding, kendo-ui

According to the kendo documentation data binding is done by adding a data-bind attribute on an element in a template and the kendo framework will figure out the details.
I put together a simple js fiddle to show the problem I'm having as this does not appear to be doing what I would expect ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

```
<script id="string" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <label>String</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: data" />
</script>

<script id="number" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="number" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="value: data" />
</script>

<script id="date" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <label>Date</label>
    <input type="date" data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: data" />
</script>

<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h2>Object Id: #: id #</h2>
    <ul class="fields">
        <li data-template="string" data-bind="source: name"></li>
        <li data-template="number" data-bind="source: age"></li>
        <li data-template="date" data-bind="source: dob"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var model = new kendo.observable({
            id: 1, age: 23, name: 'Smith', dob: '"1980-01-01T00:00:00Z"'
        });

        $(function () {
            kendo.bind($("#component"), model);
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="component"
     data-bind="source: this"
     data-template="editor" />
```

Why is this not binding the values in the fields correctly, as i just get empty text boxes implying the templating is working but the binding isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extended email trails the basic answer was "kendo doesn't work like this".
It appears to be based on conventions / peculiar behaviour that varies depending on the binding situation and I am seemingly using the wrong approach with real definition of why as the tutorials / demos appear to contradict themselves.

Be warned people. kendo is not going to be polite to you without a fight!

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me in template

```
 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">    
  <div class="k-edit-label"><label for="Name">Name</label></div>

  <input type="text" 
         class="k-input k-textbox" 
          name="Name" 
          data-bind="value: Name" 
          style="margin-left:10px">
     <br>
     <br
<div class="k-edit-label"><label for="StudentId">Student Id</label></div>
       <input type="text" 
              class="k-input k-textbox" 
              name="StudentId" 
              data-bind="value: StudentId" 
              style="margin-left:10px">
  </script>
```

Comment: It does if you only ever use kendo.bind() to trigger the template attached using data-bind="template: { name: 'template' }" but if you call kendo.render() using that template and a model it doesn't. I also found that certain combinations of objects, observables and datasources and various element bindings didn't quite tally up as you would expect.